# Are Java's Streams like JavaScript's Arrays?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, functional-programming, java-stream

I try to build the Javascript equvivalent for Java's `IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(System.err::println);` and reached

```
const IntStream = (function () {
    function range(start, end, numbers = []) {
        if (start === end) {
            return numbers
        }
        return range(start + 1, end, numbers.concat(start))
    }

    return {
        range
    }
})()

IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(number => console.log(number))
```

All the stream magic of Java is builtin in a normal JavaScript array. Why can't an `ArrayList` in Java do all same things as a `Stream` or is there a purpose I didn't figure out yet?

Comment: Look similar, behave different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array higher order functions will eagerly do the whole thing at each step.

```
const isOdd = v => v % 2 == 1;
const multiply = by => v => v * by;    

const arrRange = IntStream.range(10, 20);
const arrOdd = arrRange.filter(isOdd);
const arrOddM3 = arrOdd.map(multiply(3));
```

Here all the bindings are distinct arrays created by each of the steps. Even when you chain them the intermediate arrays are always made and the whole array at each step need to be finished before the next can begin.

```
const arrOddM3 = IntStream.range(10, 20).filter(isOdd).map(multiply(3));
arrOddM3; // ==> [33, 39, 45, 51, 57]
```

Streams are different since they only compute values when they are accessed. A stream version would look very similar.

```
const streamOddM3 = Stream.range(10, Infinity).filter(isOdd).map(multiply(3));
streamOddM3; // ==> Stream
```

Notice I have changed the end to go to infinity. I can do that because at most it calculates the very first value and some implementations doesn't do any calculations at all until you ask for the values. To force the calculations you can take some values and get them returned as an array:

```
streamOddM3.take(3); // ==> [33, 39, 45]
```

Here is a Stream implementation loosely based on the one from the [SICP videos](https://youtu.be/a2Qt9uxhNSM?t=7m24s) which work similar to Java's streams.

```
class EmptyStream {
    map() {
        return this;
    }

    filter() {
        return this;
    }

    take() {
        return [];
    }
}

class Stream extends EmptyStream {
    constructor(value, next) {
        super();
        this._next = next;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * This prevents the value to be computed more than once
     * @returns {EmptyStream|Stream}
     */
    next() {
        if( ! (this._next instanceof EmptyStream) ) {
            this._next = this._next();
        }
        return this._next;
    }

    map(fn) {
        return new Stream(fn(this.value), () => this.next().map(fn));
    }

    filter(fn) {
        return fn(this.value) ?
            new Stream(this.value, () => this.next().filter(fn)) :
            this.next().filter(fn);
    }

    take(n) {
        return n == 0 ? [] : [this.value, ...this.next().take(n && n - 1)];
    }

    static range(from, to, step = 1) {
        if (to !== undefined && ( step > 0 && from > to || step < 0 && from < to )) {
            return Stream.emptyStream;
        }
        return new Stream(from, () => Stream.range(from + step, to, step));
    }
}

Stream.emptyStream = new EmptyStream();
```

## There are alternatives to Stream that might work in their place.

In JavaScript you have [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) (aka coroutines) and you can make a map and filter generator function that takes a generator source and becomes a new generator with that transformation. Since it is already in the language it might be a better match than Streams but I haven't studied it enough to make a generator example of the above.

In Clojure you have [transducers](https://youtu.be/6mTbuzafcII) that allows you to compose steps so that an eventual list making only happens for the elements that makes it to the final result. They are easily implemented in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same because of how they proccess the data.
In LINQ (C#) or javascript, each operation on a collection must end befor calling to the next operation in the pipeline.

In streams, its different. For example:

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream()
        .filter((Integer x)-> x>1)
        .map((Integer x)->x*10)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

source collection: 1, 2 ,3

1. filter(1) -> You are not OK. Element 1 will not pass to the next operation
   in the pipeline. Now deal with element 2.
2. filter(2) -> You are OK. element 2 pass to the next operation.
   map(2) -> create new element 20 and put it in the new stream.
3. forEach(20) -> print 20. End dealing with element 2 in the source collection.
   Now deal with element 3.
4. filter(3) -> You are OK. element 3 pass to the next operation
5. map(3) -> create new element 30 and put it in the new stream.
6. forEach(20) -> print 30. No more elements in the source collection.
   finish excuting the stream.

   output:
   20
   30

Illustration:

[image]

One of the outcome of this approach is sometimes some operations in the pipeline won't go over each element because some of them filtered out in the proccess.

This explanation were taken from: [Streams In Depth By Stav Alfi](https://gist.github.com/stavalfi/969539b245fd71f18ecd14f48eed2a5d)